# Trouble with deriving the Euler-Poisson equation using Euler's approach

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

*"A First Course in the Calculus of Variations"* by Mark Kot, *§2.2. Euler’s approach* describes a method for deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation which I shall call "geometric". It is also described [here](https://preetum.nakkiran.org/lagrange.html) and in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568443/geometric-derivation-of-the-euler-lagrange-equation).  I would like to derive the general version of this equation, also called the Euler-Poisson equation

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left( -1 \right)^{k}\frac{d^{k}}{dx^{k}}\left( \frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{(k)}} \right)=0$$

for my students, they didn't like Lagrange's approach.

I seem to be having issues with going above the first derivative, $y'$, though. How does one derive the Euler-Poisson equation using the geometric approach?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to derive the EL equations in the discrete setting. You just need to replace the function $y$ by a sequence. You can then write your action as:
$$
S = \sum_{i\in\mathbb Z} G(y_i,...,y_{i+n})
$$
Varying $y$ gives:
$$
\frac{\partial S}{\partial y_i} = \sum_{k=0}^n\partial_k G(y_{i-k},...,y_{i-k+n})
$$
To make the link with the continuous limit, just rewrite:
$$
G(y_i,...y_{i+n}) = F(y_i^{(0)},...,y_i^{(n)})\Delta x
$$
with $y_i^{(k)}$ the $k$-th discrete derivative at $i$:
$$
y_i^{(k)} = \frac{1}{\Delta x^k}\sum_{l=0}^k a_{kl}y_{i+l}
$$
with the $a$ are the forward finite difference coefficients:
$$
\begin{align}
k&=0 & 1 \\
k&=1 & -1 && 1\\
k&=2 & 1 && -2 && 1 \\
\end{align} \\
a_{kl} = (-1)^{k-l}\binom{k}{l}
$$
The variation is now:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\delta S}{\delta y}\right)_i &= \frac{1}{\Delta x}\frac{\partial S}{\partial y_i} \\
&= \frac{1}{\Delta x}\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{l=k}^n\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{(l)}}(y_{i-k}^{(0)},...,y_{i-k}^{(n)})\frac{\partial y_{i-k}^{(l)}}{\partial y_i} \Delta x \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{l=0}^k\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{(k)}}\right)_{i-k}a_{kl}\Delta x^{-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{l=0}^k\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{(k)}}\right)_{i-k}a_{kl}\Delta x^{-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\left[\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{(k)}}\right)\right]_i
\end{align}
$$
where I identified the backward finite difference:
$$
\left[\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\Phi\right]_i = \frac{1}{(-\Delta x)^k}\sum_{l=0}^ka_{kl}\Phi_{i-l}
$$

This generalises to other finite difference schemes, in particular the central one where you get the same finite difference by symmetry. In general, the integration by parts translates into an Abel transform in the discrete case, which is why the order is reversed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I've been looking for. Now, do you have any ideas how I could try to simplify this a bit for my students? They really enjoyed the geometric approach for the Euler-Lagrange equation. This is really just a generalisation, though seems less geometric, no?

Comment: Glad it helped. You could translate it geometrically by adding next to nearest neighbor interactions. Scaling the coupling appropriately will give you a second derivative dependence in the Lagrangian and a 4th derivative term in the EL equations

Answer (score 1):

Consider the functional
$$
J[y] = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(x, y, y', \ldots, y^{(n)}) \,dx,
$$
where $y = y(x)$.
what we want is
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} +\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right) - \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y''}\right) + \ldots + (-1)^n \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{(n)}}\right) = 0.
$$

Let $y + \epsilon \eta$ be a variation of the function $y(x)$, where $\epsilon$ is a small parameter, and $\eta$ is a smooth function with $\eta(x_1) = \eta(x_2) = 0$. and The powers of $\eta(x_1) ,\eta(x_2)$ will also be zero for powers less than $n-1$

The variation of the functional is given by
$$
J[y + \epsilon \eta] = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(x, y + \epsilon \eta, (y + \epsilon \eta)', \ldots, (y + \epsilon \eta)^{(n)}) \,dx.
$$

Now, we consider the Taylor expansion of $F$ up to the first-order term in $\epsilon$:
$$
F(x, y + \epsilon \eta, \ldots) = F(x, y, \ldots) + \epsilon \eta \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \epsilon \eta' \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} + \ldots
$$

Substitute this expansion into the integral:
\begin{align*}
J[y + \epsilon \eta] &= \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \left[F(x, y, \ldots) + \epsilon \eta \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + \epsilon \eta' \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} + \ldots \right] \,dx \\
&= J[y] + \epsilon \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \eta \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \,dx + \epsilon \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \eta' \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \,dx + \ldots
\end{align*}

Now, we apply the fundamental lemma of the calculus of variations, which states that if a smooth function $\eta$ satisfies $\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \eta \psi \,dx = 0$ for all smooth functions $\psi$ with $\psi(x_1) = \psi(x_2) = 0$, then $\eta$ must be identically zero.

By applying this lemma to each term in the expansion, we obtain conditions for the variation to vanish:
\begin{align*}
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \eta \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \,dx &= 0, \\
\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \eta' \frac{\partial F}{\partial y'} \,dx &= 0, \\
& \vdots
\end{align*}

These conditions lead to the Euler-Lagrange equation:
$$
 \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} +\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right) - \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y''}\right) + \ldots + (-1)^n \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y^{(n)}}\right) = 0.
$$

This equation characterizes the extremal functions for the given functional $J[y]$.

I Hope it Helps , Its easy to follow as well as Intutive

Comment: That is correct and intuitive, I agree, but I said in my post that my students did not like Lagrange's approach, which is almost the same as this one. I was looking for a geometric derivation, as described [https://preetum.nakkiran.org/lagrange.html](here) :)

Comment: oh very soory ,i misread your question as if you are looking for some other derivation than geometric one i will give geometric one in other answer

Comment: honestly i never had any course so didnt know difference between them i have seen this kind of treatment in daniel's integration handbook so i did it here

Comment: It's no problem! You can of course post your derivation but I've already given away the prize for the question so unfortunately, I won't be able to reward your answer.